# HTML div responsive design with cards

Tags: python, html, responsive-design, jinja2

The title doesn't really describe my problem.
I have a web app with "cards" that describe my item, but I need it to fill up the screen, while staying the same size.

My current design is like this:
[current design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpq0z.png)

What I want my design to be like is: [design that I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eM3R9.png)

Please excuse my horrible graphic design skills and thanks in advance!

EDIT: Current code

```
<div class="row">
        {% for task in tasks %}
              <div class="card">
                <div class="alert">
                    <strong>Status: </strong> {{ task.status }}
                </div>
                {% if logo == False %}
                <img src="[redacted]" alt="Logo for {{ task.content }}" style="width:100%">
                {% else %}
                <img src="{{ task.logo }}" alt="Logo for {{ task.content }}" style="width:50%">
                {% endif %}
                <h1>{{ task.content }}</h1>
                <p>{{ task.description }}</p>
                <a href='https://{{ task.website }}'><button>Visit {{ task.content }}'s website</button></a>
                <div class="btn-group"><p><a href='delete/{{ task.id }}'><button style="width:50%">Delete</button></a><a href='update/{{ task.id }}'><button style="width:50%">Edit</button></a></p></div>
              </div>
              <br>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: would you please share the code? or website you are using?

Comment: added the code, does you need this?

Comment: @MuhammadAliDEV It's in jinja, but I've updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use css stylesheet for creating a card like structure.
An example code is given below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/* Float four columns side by side */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

/* Remove extra left and right margins, due to padding */
.row {margin: 0 -5px;}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Responsive columns */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}

/* Style the counter cards */
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Responsive Column Cards</h2>
<p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="card">
      <h3>Card 1</h3>
      <p>Some text</p>
      <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div class="card">
      <h3>Card 2</h3>
      <p>Some text</p>
      <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="column">
    <div class="card">
      <h3>Card 3</h3>
      <p>Some text</p>
      <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="column">
    <div class="card">
      <h3>Card 4</h3>
      <p>Some text</p>
      <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```